# ActivityNotFoundException crash when starting "open url" intent on Chrome 86.0.4240.75

Tags: android, android-webview, android-chrome

Chrome for Android [**version 86.0.4240.75**](https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/2020/10/chrome-for-android-update.html) was released just a few days ago. The rollout has barely started, but we're seeing a new crash whose numbers are going straight up, on devices using that version of Chrome / Android System WebView.

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "text/html")
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE)
startActivity(intent)
```

It looks like for **any url**, on **any device** using version 86.0.4240.75, the above code crashes with ActivityNotFoundException:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent 
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1854) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1544)
```

Seems like a bug in Chrome, but has anyone figured out a workaround yet?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A bit surprising, but I found an easy workaround. Actually two: remove the **MIME type** or remove the **category**.

This works fine even with 86.0.4240.75:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE)
startActivity(intent)
```

This does too:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "text/html")
startActivity(intent)
```

(I'm not sure what the benefit of defining `text/html` or `CATEGORY_BROWSABLE` was in the first place, as neither seems mandatory.)